# Calculate grid width given a set of points

Tags: opengl

I am drawing a grid in opengl using this -

```cpp
void draw_grid()
{
    glColor3f(0.32, 0.32, 0.32);

    int iterations = int(WIDTH / grid_width) + 1;

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int x = i * grid_width;
        glVertex2f(x, 0);
        glVertex2f(x, HEIGHT);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int y = i * grid_width;
        glVertex2f(0, y);
        glVertex2f(WIDTH, y);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

And, then I plot points at the intersections of this grid.

I am implementing simple dda method for drawing lines.

For endpoints (2,3) and (15, 8) I get this as output -

[image]

But, for endpoints (2,3) and (35, 8) I get this -

[image]

You can see that for the second case some points get plotted outside the window and thus are not visible.

This happens because I have hardcoded the `grid_width`.

I understand that more the difference between the endpoints the smaller the `grid_width` is supposed to be.

But I can't figure out how exactly to calculate the `grid_width` so that no matter what endpoints are given they are drawn in the bounds of the window.

Comment: `grid_width = int(WIDTH / maxC) + 1);` - `maxC` is the maximum coordinate (35).

Comment: This works, but still some points are out of window. Replacing + 1 with - 1 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to determine the `grid_width` depending on the maximum coordinate. The maximum width of the grid is `WIDTH / maxC` where `maxC` is the maximum coordinate. e.g.:

```
grid_width = int(WIDTH / maxC);
```